# Unity- make object follow but not run into another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, game-physics, game-development

Ok, so I’ve read up extensively on Vector3.MoveTowards to manipulate a gameobject’s position, or making it move towards a waypoint.

I’m having an issue figuring out logistically how to have an object “walk alongside” another - where object A is the leader and object B could be across the room, but when a bool flips object B needs to “run over” and start moving alongside object A-

This differs from a typical follow because I can’t have object B making contact with object A- it shouldn’t be following A’s position, but rather take up the closest point on its “periphery” -

I thought maybe a sphere collider.? What is the best way to tackle this “alongside walking” kind of follow?

Comment: Have you tried adding a navmesh agent to these characters and then baking the level navmesh? You can then use `agent.SetDestination();`

Comment: Can you provide your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be pretty simple - use iTween with ClosestPointOnBounds for a collider.